# Enable tab spacing for inserting programming code on Stack Overflow

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, code-formatting

I think writing code is pretty hard to write in the textbox, having to press spacebar so many times. Wouldn't it be great to have a shortcut of some kind? In all text editors, a tab is a shortcut. Spaces aren't really friendly.

For example, I press the TAB key, and it writes 4 spaces, writing code begins. Also, when you go to new line of coding, it would maintain the number of spaces you're currently at (nested code).

Comment: So `Ctrl + k` when selecting a block of code doesn't work for you?

Comment: Right. It does, but that's only to write something on the first line, it doesn't support nested tags.

Comment: Nested tags? What do you mean? As for formatting - most people type something up in an IDE before pasting it in (some even compile it). It ensures that the piece of code is properly indented to begin with (and if it compiles, it is code that can be copy-pasted by those trying to answer).

Comment: Alternatively, learn how easy it is to use the keyboard to navigate forms on web sites. And then see that using Tab for something completely different on SE might be a real pain...